# Map row and columns to store in firebase database

Tags: arrays, json, angular, typescript, arraylist

I am using google sheet data to display in my page using angular. When I tried to display data it comes in the form of array and field names as `0 1 2 3` . I wanted to know how can we map row and column so that I can display the data in correct way. Here is teh screenshot of my response that I am getting.[image]

column:

```
(3) ['Id', 'Name', 'Major']
0: "Id"
1: "Name"
2: "Major"
```

Row:

```
0: Array(3)
0: 202
1: "word"
2: "comp"

1: Array(3)
0: 203
1: "John"
2: "science"
```

what I am trying is to get data like: UserData:

```
Id:202,
Name:"word"
Major:"comp"

Id:203,
Name:"John"
Major:"Science"
```

Method I have used is

```
excelData(){

   var sf = "https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1qeCEUlVt_hnuyhnoT1wxMMSv7kZW1s4cUIRLynJ0TxQ/gviz/tq";
 this.http.get(sf,{responseType: 'text'}).subscribe(res=>{
   const data =res.toString().match(/google\.visualization\.Query\.setResponse\(([\s\S\w]+)\)/);
   if(data && data.length==2){
     const obj=JSON.parse(data[1]);
     const table=obj.table;
     const header =  table.cols.map(({label}) => label);
     const rows = table.rows.map(({c}) => c.map(({v}) => v));
     console.log(header);
     console.log(rows); 
     this.collection.doc().set(Object.assign({}, rows));
    }
       
 });
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your situation, how about the following sample script?

#### Sample script:

In this sample script, your values of `header` and `rows` are used.

```
const values = rows.map(e => header.reduce((o, f, j) => Object.assign(o, {[f]: e[j]}), {}));
```

- When your sample values are used, `values` returns the following values.

  ```
    [
      {"Id":202,"Name":"word","Major":"comp"},
      {"Id":203,"Name":"John","Major":"science"},
      {"Id":204,"Name":"nsia","Major":"cmpi"}
    ]
  ```

#### References:

- [map()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map)
- [reduce()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce)
- [Object.assign()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/assign)